# Missing data: conduct logit or random effects?

Tags: modeling, panel-data, missing-data, random-effects-model, logit

I would like to conduct on analysis that analyzes whether personality traits predict job search activity and contract type. I have a panel data set of about 15 waves. I wanted to conduct a logistic regression or a random effects model, but while the models work (and the results make sense) I am unsure whether this is the right approach?

**Variables:**

Personality: continuous variable, time-variant, lagged value

Contract type: dichotomous, time-variant, only reported when becoming re-employed

Activity: dichotomous (1=active, 0=inactive), time-variant, many missing

Duration: duration of unemployment

Event: ==1 if becoming re-employed, repeated (multiple employment-entries possible)

Employed: ==1 if employed, ==0 if unemployed

**Example data set**:

```
id  year  employed event  duration personality contract   activity    
1   2002  0        0      4        2                      .    
1   2003  1        1      5        2.3         permanent  .    
1   2004  0        0      1        2.4                    1    
1   2005  0        0      2        2.4                    0
1   2006  0        0      3        2.3                    1
1   2007  1        1      4        3           temporary  .
```

This is an example on activity worked in Stata:

```
xtlogit activity personality duration education age age^2, i(pid) re

Random-effects logistic regression                  Number of obs     =      2,960    
Group variable: pid                                 Number of groups  =      1,130

Random effects u_i ~ Gaussian                       Obs per group:    
                                                              min =          1    
                                                              avg =        2.6    
                                                              max =         10    

Integration method: mvaghermite                
Integration pts.  =         12

                                                Wald chi2(5)      =     152.69    
Log likelihood  = -1651.3757                    Prob > chi2       =     0.0000    

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     activity |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]        
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
  personality |  -.2550342   .0346134    -7.37   0.000    -.3228752   -.1871931    
duration_time |  -.1003427   .0188603    -5.32   0.000    -.1373083   -.0633772    
          age |   .3906647   .0535773     7.29   0.000     .2856551    .4956744    
         ageq |  -.0042412    .000624    -6.80   0.000    -.0054642   -.0030183    
     vbilzeit |  -.1641792   .0402211    -4.08   0.000    -.2430112   -.0853472    
        _cons |  -4.662737   1.161602    -4.01   0.000    -6.939434    -2.38604    
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     /lnsig2u |   1.531009   .1366292                      1.263221    1.798797    
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      sigma_u |   2.150079   .1468817                      1.880636    2.458124    
          rho |   .5842297    .033188                      .5180854    .6474729    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I didn't specifically do anything to the many missing values, because I am not sure how to actually handle them. I would rather not impute them.

And for contract:

```
xtlogit contract personality duration_time age ageq vbilzeit, i(pid) re


Random-effects logistic regression                  Number of obs     =        737
Group variable: pid                                 Number of groups  =        654

Random effects u_i ~ Gaussian                       Obs per group:
                                                              min =          1    
                                                              avg =        1.1    
                                                              max =          3    

Integration method: mvaghermite                
Integration pts.  =         12

                                                Wald chi2(5)      =      17.46    
Log likelihood  = -488.51147                    Prob > chi2       =     0.0037     

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
     contract |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]    
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------    
  personality |   .1151225   .0480572     2.40   0.017     .0209321    .2093128    
duration_time |   -.008639   .0258621    -0.33   0.738    -.0593279    .0420498    
          age |    .028171   .0498828     0.56   0.572    -.0695976    .1259396    
         ageq |   .0000464   .0005575     0.08   0.934    -.0010462     .001139    
     vbilzeit |  -.0703109   .0388249    -1.81   0.070    -.1464063    .0057846    
        _cons |  -.7030184   1.171701    -0.60   0.549     -2.99951    1.593473    
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------    
     /lnsig2u |  -.1441078   .8860183                     -1.880672    1.592456    
--------------+----------------------------------------------------------------    
      sigma_u |   .9304808   .4122115                      .3904967    2.217162    
          rho |   .2083409   .1461354                      .0442975    .5990741    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: If you want to know if your models make sense I think you will need to show us one or two example models. While you are editing your question to do that you might also say how you dealt with the missing activity variable.

Comment: How much missing do you have in the data?

Comment: I added two example models. I am very sorry for the spacing, I tried around but I am not sure how to actually make nice tables.

Comment: For my "activity"-variable: more than 2/3 are missing. The variable "contract" is usually nonmissing.

Comment: do you know the missingness-generating process of "activity?"  Is it due to a skip pattern or something else?

Comment: I am glad you asked this. Everyone who is unemployed gets asked this question. So as long as employed==0 people are questioned and apparently missing is due to refusal.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe it would be better to conduct a regular logit-analysis for contracty type (with lagged personality) and then maybe to conduct a multi-level logit analysis for activity? I am just not sure whether all of these are a smart idea given that I have repeated events (see variable description for "event")?